# plotting eigenvalues with devoted level coloring

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

I am about to plot eigenvalues of a matrix versus varying`j`'s.

```
Hma[j_Integer] = {{0.1*j^2, 0, 0, 0.2*j, 0}, {0, 0.1*j, 0, 0.2*j^3, 
0}, {0, 0.1*j, 0, 0, 0.2*j}, {0.1*j^2, 0, 0, 0, 0.2*j}, {0, 0, 
0.1*j, 0.2*j, 0}};
data=Flatten[Table[Thread[{j, Re@Eigenvalues[Hma[j]]}], {j, n}], 1];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

I am trying to have a plot with specified color as I manually showed above.
(higher eigenvalues (first ones) with a same color (for example Red above), seconds with same color (and different from the first ones for example Yellow))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `data` in the question, the following also works.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[Split[data, First[#1] === First[#2] &]], 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Purple, Orange, Red}]
```

[image]

This, of course, assumes that `data` already is ordered by size.  If not, use

```
ListPlot[SortBy[Transpose[Split[data, First[#1] === First[#2] &]], Last],
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Purple, Orange, Red}]
```

And, if larger markers (or other such presentation changes) are desired, use

```
ListPlot[SortBy[Transpose[Split[data, First[#1] === First[#2] &]], Last], 
    PlotStyle -> ({#, PointSize[Large]} & /@ {Blue, Green, Purple, Orange, Red})]
```

[image]

Note that the `Green` points are scarcely visible, because they approximately coincide with the `Purple` points.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
 n=5;
 dt = Table[Select[SortBy[data, Last], #[[1]] == j &], {j, 1, n}];

 ListPlot[Table[dt[[1 ;; n, eid]], {eid, 1, 5}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Purple, Orange, Red}]
```

[image]